# captcha sometime work and something not working in IE8 under https://

Tags: php, https

I have wrote the following code in php to generate a captcha. The code is run under https:// and works perfectly fine in IE9, Mozilla, Chrome and Safari. However, in IE8, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not (shows a broken image). Does anyone know what is going on? Can anyone see anything wrong with the code below that would cause problems in IE8:

```
     class Captcha_generator{

        function __construct()
        {

        }

        public function get_image($callType)
        {
            $font = './image/MONOFONT.TTF';
            $width='140';
            $height='40';
            $font_size = $height * 0.75;
            $angle = 3; 

            //Now lets use md5 to generate a totally random string 
            $md5 = md5(microtime() * mktime()); 

            /* 
            We dont need a 32 character long string so we trim it down to 5 
            */ 
            $string = substr($md5,0,5);
            /* 
            Now for the GD stuff, for ease of use lets create 
            the image from a background image. 
            */ 


            $captcha = imagecreate($width, $height);
rand(0,255));


            /* 
            Lets set the colours, the colour $line is used to generate lines. 
            Using a blue misty colours. The colour codes are in RGB 
            */ 

            $background_color = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 255, 255, 255);
            $text_color = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 20, 40, 100);
            $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 100, 120, 180);

            /* generate random dots in background */
            for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
             imagefilledellipse($captcha, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
            }
            /* generate random lines in background */
            for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
             imageline($captcha, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
            }



            /* 
            Encrypt and store the key inside of a session 
            */ 

            $_SESSION['captcha_key'] = md5("SDFSDTRSDERGTGGT".$string."AAAAA"); 

            /* 
            Output the image 
            */ 

            imagettftext($captcha, $font_size, $angle, 30, 30, $text_color, $font , $string);
            imagepng($captcha, './image/captcha.png');


            if($callType == "internal")
            {
                return "<img style='z-index:90' width='130' height='35' src='image/captcha.png?".time()."' />; 
                        <input type='hidden' name='powerCode' value='".$_SESSION['captcha_key']."'/>";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "<img style='z-index:90' width='130' height='35' src='image/captcha.png?".time()."' />";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='powerCode' value='".$_SESSION['captcha_key']."'/>";
            }
        }


     }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  Broken image? Fails to validate?

Comment: It could be that the image is currently being written to since you are writing the captcha to the same image (captcha.png) which must be shared for everyone.  I would use `imagepng($captcha, './image/' . $_SESSION['captcha_key'] . '.png');` instead.

Comment: would be better to output  a stream to the browser rather than saving a file.

Comment: There is no error checking in your code, so IE8 might just do work correctly because you are sending garbage to the browser. Instead, introduce error-checks, do logging if something wents wrong and follow the log so you know when something goes wrong.

Comment: @Dagon: how to output a stream to the browser??

Comment: @Jin Yong: See http://php.net/manual/function.imagepng.php - do not set the filename parameter, then it goes to standard output which goes into the browser.

Comment: @hakre,@Dagon:If im using magepng, how can I display this image on my display page? Especially I'm calling this function by using ajax

Comment: ajax? Well then I'd say, you should return it as string in form of a data-uri: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer, and only showing how to turn the captcha PNG image into a data-uri:

```
        /* 
        Output the image 
        */ 

        imagettftext($captcha, $font_size, $angle, 30, 30, $text_color, $font , $string);
        ob_start();
        imagepng($captcha);
        $captchaURI= 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
```

Pleae note the usage of output control functions here. They are often very useful, e.g. as well to make your function echo or return the string without duplicating the code:

```
        ob_start();
        echo "<img style='z-index:90' width='130' height='35' src='", $captchaURI, "' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='powerCode' value='", $_SESSION['captcha_key'], "'/>";
        if ($callType == "internal")
        {
             return ob_get_clean();
        }
        ob_end_flush();
```